# How to work with LaTeX such that files are interchangeable linux/unix/windows?

Tags: windows, linux, input-encodings

I am mosly using `pdflatex`. One recurring problem is that the encoding
used on Linux (my system), UTF8, is different from on Windows, I use

```
\inputencoding{utf8}
```

on Windows one must use (well, to write spanish ...)

```
\inputencoding{latin1}
```

and files must be converted when moved between systems. Is there a way to organize the workflow such that the same input file can be used on both systems?
without conversion and without any editing?  (possibly invoking change to XelaTeX/LuaTeX, if necessary)

Comment: As long as you're using a Windows editor that supports Unicode (pretty much anything except WinEdt) you should be able to use `utf8` on all machines.

Comment: @AlanMunn: there's good news regarding WinEdt and Unicode support --- version 7, released ca 3 months ago, is fully Unicode-capable. :-)

Comment: @Mico Good to know.  I've made this a little clearer in the big [LaTeX editors/IDE question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn: I guess it's pretty much anything except TeXnicCenter (except for the alpha version).

Answer (score 7):

Use a cross-platform Unicode editor like TeXworks/TeXmaker/TeXstudio where you set in the input encoding independent of the OS encoding.

For example TeXmaker recognises and suggests the recommended font encoding written by a third person to retain the consistency.

Its always better to write `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to reveal your input encoding for third person so that he opens the document in the same encoding when using pdflatex.

On Windows, with the help of cross-platform Unicode editors one can use `latin1`, `utf8` or even `utf8x` encoding and share it in Linux without any trouble.

Comment: LyX isn't a TeX editor: it's a separate system that really shouldn't be recommended as an equivalent to an editor. Also, if you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you shouldn't load `inputenc`.